# Postgres - spaces and special characters in column name - how to select these in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table in postgres test1 and columns **"Username","# of Applications", "# of R Applications" .**

when tried to query these using select query i get error-

```
select Username, "# of Applications","# of R Applications" from public.test1
```

Error
    ERROR:  column "username" does not exist
    LINE 1: select Username, "# of Applications" from public.test1...

Similarly for all other 2 columns as well....

how do i select these columns in select query?

Comment: Run the following and post the result: `SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE schema_name = 'public' AND table_name = 'test1' ORDER BY ordinal_position;`

Comment: column_name
Username
"# of Applications"
"# of R Application"

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 10):

`Username` is unquoted, so becomes `username` which the error suggests.

If your table has a column named `Username`, this should work

```
select "Username", "# of Applications","# of R Applications" from public.test1
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into, if i query 

select "Username"  from public.test1 it works but when i do

select "Username", "# of Applications","# of R Applications" from public.test1  i get error
ERROR:  column "# of Applications" does not exist
LINE 1: select "Username", "# of Applications" from public.

ERROR: column "# of Applications" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Columns in table as displayed by information_schema
Username               ---Doesn't have double quotes
"# of Applications"   --- has double quotes in the name
"# of R Applications"

Comment: @Geeme when you ran `SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE schema_name = 'public' AND table_name = 'test1' ORDER BY ordinal_position;` it shows the third column is `"# of R Application"` **not** `"# of R Applications"` as the error suggests.

Comment: it was my typo mistake - but third column is "# of R Applications". But the error is about special character #, i think postgres doesn't handle like it on column name.

Comment: This answer helped me delete a column name with (accidental) special characters: `alter table "foo" drop column "$bar";`